# How often does as spring property get updated when value in application.properties changes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would to perform a task at a scheduled time every hour and did the following using @Scheduled. The code below does execute the task 5 minutes after the hour, every hour. However, if I change the property after the application starts to "    0 10 * * * *", will it read the value and change the task schedule to run 10 minutes after the hour?

```
@Component
public class DataCleanupTask {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataCleanupTask.class);
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss a");

    @Scheduled(cron = "${data.cleanup.task.schedule.cron}")
    public void cleanupData() {
        LOGGER.debug("Starting data cleanup at " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}

# application.properties
# Schedules a task to run 5 minutes after the hour, every hour
data.cleanup.task.schedule.cron=0 5 * * * *
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Spring application, Properties are read - and all references to them are processed - on system startup (by a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`); changing the properties file after the application has started will not have any impact until the application is restarted.

In order to reconfigure your system in runtime you will need to expose ways to modify them from the outside, e.g. using JMX.

Answer (score 1):

As marthursson has said: Spring applies on startup, but doesn't refresh property values afterward.

If you are looking for this kind of functionality, you might mant to try [apache commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/).

Here's a blog post that show how it use it with spring to watch changes in a properties file: [Reloadable properties file with Spring using Apache Commons Configuration](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/reloadedable-properties-file-spring-using-apache-commons-configuration/).